How to read a .txt file in reverse order using Batch
I have a data.txt file that I parse through in my .cmd script, I go through it from the first line to the last. I want to start from the last line and go to the first instead.
 FOR /F "EOL=; TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%r IN (datafile) DO
     (CALL :DeleteFolder %%r)
How would I be able to reverse the order in which it is read?
I have tried finding the syntax for the "FOR /....." but it seems impossible to find good documentation for .cmd or batch files (question within a question, is a .cmd file the same as a batch file and a .bat file, the syntax seems to be the same and whenever I search for .cmd file it will show me batch file help).
This is the sample data file I am working with now for testing purposes, the real data file will be a couple hundred lines and changes frequently, it should be around 300 lines. It is basically dictating a folder and subfolder structure.
; This is a comment line
DEV1
DEV2
DEV3
DEV4
DEV5
DEV6
DEV7
DEV8
DEV9
DEV10
; This is a comment line


is a .cmd file the same as a batch file and a .bat file - there are some minor differences, but essentially, yes.

Please edit a representative sample of your data file into your question. Would SORTing it in reverse help?

You cannot "reverse the order in which it is read"! The file would still be read from the start. What you'd have the option to do is to read all of the lines from the start of file, and store each line in reverse order. As you can imagine, in all but small files, this will either require a large memory buffer or a temporary file. Also in your example EOL=; TOKENS=1 is not required and CALL :DeleteFolder %%r should be CALL :DeleteFolder "%%~r".

The file I am reading is updated constantly so I cant change the contents of it. I am currently building this solution with a smaller sample of the actual data file since that one is quite large.


create a temporary file with line numbers (while removing comment lines when desired)
Count the number of lines to process
Use a for /L loop to process them backwards
delete the tempfile (optional)

    @echo off
    setlocal
    
    set "file=data.txt"
    REM create a file with line numbers (while removing comments):
    findstr /bv ";" "%file%" | findstr /n "^" > "%file%.tmp"
    
    REM find number of lines:
    for /f %%i in ('type "%file%.tmp"^|find /c /v ""') do set lines=%%i
    
    REM process them in reverse order:
    for /l %%i in (%lines%,-1,1) do (
      for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%x in ('findstr /b "%%i:" "%file%.tmp"') do (
        echo processing line number %%x:        %%y
      )
    )
    del "%file%.tmp"

There is a read operation for each line (plus one to create the tempfile and one to count the lines), but just a single write operation (creating the tempfile). No data is held in memory (except the line to process), so there is no danger of exceeding space for variables or recursion limit.
Empty lines are kept (there are none in your sample data), but can be filtered out with another findstr, when needed.

Thanks, that worked it reversed my data file! in the console. However, when I insert the call: DeleteFolder it doesnt work. As in where would my function call go?

I got it to work, thank you!

The short answer: you can't. The file is read in natural order always. The usual way to solve this problem is storing all file lines in variables and then process the variables in reversed order. Problems with this method arise when the file is large, because the space for variables is limited and the process becomes slower as the file becomes larger...
I devised an interesting method to process file lines in reversed order that does not use variables. Instead, it keeps each pending line in a FOR replaceable parameter, and it process several lines via nested recursive calls of the subroutine that have the FOR command. In this way, the maximum number of lines that can be processed via this method is the maximum level of subroutine calls that cmd.exe supports, that I think is several hundred.
Anyway, this method is interesting!  ;)
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "last=1"
:rolling
set "first=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (data.txt) do if defined last (
   set /A first+=1
   if !first! equ %last% (
      set /A last+=1
      call :rolling
      echo(%%a
      set "last="
   )
)
exit /B


Another possible solution is to permanently reverse the lines of the file, and then process it as usual. This can be achieved via this code:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem/> output.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   (
   echo(%%a
   type output.txt
   ) > temp.txt
   move /Y temp.txt output.txt > NUL
)


Thanks for the help, I am trying to implement it now. I am having trouble understanding where I would call my DeleteFolder function. I am new to Batch scripting, why are you using ! to enclose the first variable and not %% like variables are usually enclosed with and is the "do if defined" last a True/False check?

@NimaPishva the second example should be pretty obvious.  The output.txt file is the file reversed.  So now you just use that with your existing for command. FOR /F "EOL=; TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%r IN (output.txt) DO (CALL :DeleteFolder %%r)

thank you, I was able to get it to work.

Well, this method should run faster than another one that execute a findstr command in every line of the file...

Recursion limit is at 339. That's frightening close to "a couple hundred ... around 300". Prepare for Stack Overflow (pun intended) if you use this (recursion) method. Interesting solution though. The second suggestion does at least two write operations per line (should be "slow" on rotating disks).

I successfully used the below batch, however Original.txt has spaces (in between each line there is 1 CRLF) and Reversed.txt removes all CRLF (Carriage Return/Line Feed).
Is there a way to keep the CRLFs in Reversed.txt?
@echo off
ren *.txt Original.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem/> Reversed.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Original.txt) do (
   (
   echo(%%a
   type Reversed.txt
   ) > temp.txt
   move /Y temp.txt Reversed.txt > NUL
)


this is the answers section. If you have a question, please ask (blue button top right). Provide a link to this question, if you feel it's helpful.
